# Migrating from Win7 to Win10 - will my C# projects work?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, migration

I plan to install Windows 10 instead of Windows 7. But I'm a bit scary about it. Does my old projects from Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate will work?

I've got few apps in C# .Net Framework 3.5 which I have to maintain and I'm not sure, whether newest visual studio on Windows 10 will work correctly with such old framework. If so, should I install same VS as before, or newest one?

Comment: This isn't really a programming question. But "should work fine" and "should work fine with either IDE, might as well update" - that do?

Comment: Any VS and any OS is fine, but you may face some issue with style.